# Install inotify PHP service into XAMPP x64-8.2.4-0 on Windows?

Tags: php, xampp, server-sent-events, inotify

I have been exploring **inotify ** PHP service for XAMPP x64-8.2.4-0 on Windows so a webpage will reload when another file is modified.

I cant quite understand how to implement it.

I have done polling before with SSE, but would like a better solution.

My dev space is XAMPP on Windows, and online hosting is on Linux

Cheers

I have the inotify package downloaded and the latest PHP in case I have to compile this outside of XAMPP (not entirely sure of those steps on Windows)

Comment: I cannot find a pre-comipled dll

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not sysadmin stuff like installing / using existing software.  Might be on topic on https://superuser.com/ (probably not https://serverfault.org/ for XAMPP).  Also note that the [inotify] tag is about the Linux system call of the same name.  If there's a PHP module for it, it might or might not support whatever similar functionality exists on Windows to monitor a directory for changes in an event-based way.

Comment: @PeterCordes my understanding of XAMPP (see, e.g., [the Usage section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP#Usage) or [the project website](https://www.apachefriends.org/hosting.html), stating *"XAMPP provides an ideal local development environment, but is not meant for production deployments."*) is that it's pretty much entirely intended for local development and not actually running a production server.  That would make it a tool "used primarily for programming", per [our on-topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RyanM: Good point.  I wondered (when retagging after commenting) why the [tag:xampp] tag had 12.6k questions, and if we were counting this as a dev environment.  I thought of it as just packing of existing widely-used software, apart from its GUI control stuff, but on second thought there probably good arguments for keeping its questions on SO.  There's clearly precedent for it.  Some questions would probably also be on-topic on superuser (but not serverfault), but with a large collection of XAMPP questions here, here is presumably good.